# Indentation broken with all \input{files.tex}

Tags: latex, indentation

Everything is in the title :

- a  `master.tex` file contains several `\input{subfileXX.tex}` ;
- the indentation works in the master file but not in the subfiles. The TAB key acts like in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that your other files use `tex-plain-mode` instead of `latex-mode`.  The `.tex` extension is used for both, so Emacs tries to guess, and it tends to err on the side of `tex-plain-mode`.

You can add a `-*- mode: latex -*-` somewhere on the first line of your files to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks ! It suffices to add `% -*- mode: latex -*-` as the first line.